# Memory get wrong after using the sleep function

Tags: c, for-loop, time, malloc, sleep

There is a char** array to store structs, which has ID, action and current time. Therefore, after every second, there will be a new customer. But when I iterate the char** array, the time output will be the same as the last one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

char* get_current_time(){
    time_t current_time;
    struct tm* time_info;
    static char time_string[9];

    /*Get the current time. */
    current_time = time(NULL);
    
    /*Convert the local time to local time. */
    time_info = localtime(&current_time);
    
    /*Format the time string. */
    strftime(time_string, sizeof(time_string), "%H:%M:%S", time_info);
    
    return time_string;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "getTime.h"

typedef struct cusDetails
{
    int cusId;
    char cusAct;
    char* cusTime;
}cusDetails;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int numCus = atoi(argv[1]);
    int i;
    char* cusActList = "ABCDEFGHI";
    
    cusDetails* customers = malloc(numCus*sizeof(cusDetails));
    
    for (i = 0; i <numCus; i++)
    {
        customers[i].cusId = i+1;
        customers[i].cusAct = cusActList[i];
        customers[i].cusTime = get_current_time();
        printf("The cutomer in time %s\n", customers[i].cusTime);

        sleep(1);
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i <numCus; i++)
    {
        printf("Customer: %d, for %c, at %s\n", customers[i].cusId, customers[i].cusAct, customers[i].cusTime);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The input "./a.out 5" and the output would be:
The cutomer in time 09:20:58
The cutomer in time 09:20:59
The cutomer in time 09:21:00
The cutomer in time 09:21:01
The cutomer in time 09:21:02

Customer: 1, for A, at 09:21:02
Customer: 2, for B, at 09:21:02
Customer: 3, for C, at 09:21:02
Customer: 4, for D, at 09:21:02
Customer: 5, for E, at 09:21:02

Please help and tell me what is helped there? and how to prevent it happen

Comment: I add ```char* timeStr``` then ```timeStr = get_current_time(); customer[i] = time;``` it is also the same output

Answer (score 3):

`customers[i].cusTime = get_current_time();` copies a pointer, the same pointer each time.  `printf("... %s\n", ..., customers[i].cusTime);` then always prints the contents refenced by that same pointer.

Instead,  copy the *string*.

```
typedef struct cusDetails {
    int cusId;
    char cusAct;
    // char* cusTime;
    char cusTime[9];
}cusDetails;

// customers[i].cusTime = get_current_time();
strcpy(customers[i].cusTime, get_current_time());
```

Comment: it works!!!!!! with char cusTime[9] then the type would be the compatible type! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @MartinChan `char *cusTime[9];` typo changed to `char cusTime[9];`.

Answer (score 1):

1. As your time_string is fixed length I suggest you change `char *cusTime` to `char cusTime[TIME_LEN]` to reflect that.  `static` variables is somewhat of a code smell as it's not thread safe.  This is why I am just passing the string into `get_current_time()` instead of asking caller to copy it which, as you found, is an error prune design.
2. Added a check on `argc` so your program doesn't segfault if you forgot to specify the required number argument.  Btw, prefer `strtol()` or write your own as `atoi()` silently convert errors to 0.
3. Prefer to minimize the scope of variables.  I made `int i` local to both of the two loops that use it.  This also avoids the question if those two loops communicate via `i` (sometimes you use it count number of elements).
4. Not fixed but prefer passing the variable instead of the type to `sizeof`.  It usually shorter and they follow the same pattern irregardless of the type.  In practice I find them more robust to change; changing the type name is usually global change while a variable name change is usually localized.

```
struct type *t = malloc(sizeof *t * count);
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define TIME_LEN 9

typedef struct cusDetails {
    int cusId;
    char cusAct;
    char cusTime[TIME_LEN];
} cusDetails;

void get_current_time(char time_string[TIME_LEN]){
    time_t current_time;
    struct tm* time_info;

    /*Get the current time. */
    current_time = time(NULL);

    /*Convert the local time to local time. */
    time_info = localtime(&current_time);

    /*Format the time string. */
    strftime(time_string, TIME_LEN, "%H:%M:%S", time_info);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc != 2) {
        printf("argument required\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int numCus = atoi(argv[1]);
    char* cusActList = "ABCDEFGHI";

    cusDetails* customers = malloc(numCus*sizeof(cusDetails));
    for (int i = 0; i <numCus; i++) {
        customers[i].cusId = i+1;
        customers[i].cusAct = cusActList[i];
        get_current_time(customers[i].cusTime);
        printf("The cutomer in time %s\n", customers[i].cusTime);
        sleep(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <numCus; i++)
        printf("Customer: %d, for %c, at %s\n", customers[i].cusId, customers[i].cusAct, customers[i].cusTime);
    return 0;
}
```

and example session:

```
$ ./a.out 3
The cutomer in time 22:02:34
The cutomer in time 22:02:35
The cutomer in time 22:02:36
Customer: 1, for A, at 22:02:34
Customer: 2, for B, at 22:02:35
Customer: 3, for C, at 22:02:36
```